# Using jsoup in java

Tags: java, jsoup

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           for (int i=21;i<30;i++){
               path="https://www.super.kg/media/audio/"+i;
               Document dc = Jsoup.connect(path).timeout(6000).get();
               Elements body = dc.select("div.clear");

               for (Element item : body) {
                   String    method = item.select("div.media_mtspan.video_desc_text").html();
                   method= method.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
                   System.out.println(method);

                   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\cholp\\Desktop\\out.txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer.println(method);
                    writer.close();
                }

            } 
}
```

help me please, cant write variable "method" to file. after running the programm there is nothing in file

Comment: System.out.println(method);
Can you see 'method' variable in console?

Comment: yes, it gives in console

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using selector like `div.clear` because `.clear` is very likely a class to style the layout and may select lots of unwanted elements, in your case I would recommend using selector such as `div.media_mt`, which is meaningful in the particular music website.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
    for (Element item : body) {
        String method = item.select("div.media_mtspan.video_desc_text").html();
        method = method.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
        System.out.println(method);

        // Here
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\cholp\\Desktop\\out.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(method);
        writer.close();
    }
```

`PrintWriter(String fileName)` will use the following code to construct a `PrintWriter` instance:

```
public PrintWriter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))),
         false);
}
```

By default, `FileOutputStream` truncates the file and print the content (`method`), as a result the last `method` will be print in the file, and, the last `method` happens to be empty, so the writing seems not work but actually it does, to solve the problem, try to replace `new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\cholp\\Desktop\\out.txt", "UTF-8")` with `new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\cholp\\Desktop\\out.txt"), "UTF-8")), /*append*/ true)`, or better, pull the writer out of for loop:

```
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\cholp\\Desktop\\out.txt", "UTF-8");

    for (Element item : body) {
        String method = item.select("div.media_mtspan.video_desc_text").html();
        method = method.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
        System.out.println(method);

        writer.append(method);
    }

    writer.close();
```

Comment: It's the ctor that truncates, not the `print*` methods. Use `new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (new FileOutputStream (filename, true/*append*/), charset))` -- or `new PW (new FOS (,true))` if the default charset is acceptable. Or usually better open it once, before the loop, and close after.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for reminding, I'll update my answer for future reader

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 , KID94 thank you for your explanation, i get what i wanted)